# Pycharm not recognizing installed modules

Tags: python, module, path, pycharm, interpreter

I'm working on an ex-collegue's script and I'm having an issue with a module in Pycharm.
The row with issue is:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

This module was marked in red as it was not installed. I tried to install it in pycharm but, even if it results as successfully installed, it is still marked in red and if I try to run i got following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

If I go to Project Interpreter settings, I can see the crypto module under python3.11 interpreter (which is the one I'm trying to use to run the script).
Looking at other questions here, I ran 'pip show Crypto' and this is the output:

```
Name: crypto
Version: 1.4.1
Summary: Simple symmetric GPG file encryption and decryption
Home-page: https://github.com/chrissimpkins/crypto
Author: Christopher Simpkins
Author-email: git.simpkins@gmail.com
License: MIT license
Location: `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages`
```

I also checked this path

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
```

is already present in the interpreter paths. Interpreter paths are listed below:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\DLLs
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
```

Really I don't know how to solve this problem. Nothing I found in previous topics seems to work for me

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong package for what you are trying to do. You want to:

`pip install pycryptodome`

According to the installation instructions [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/cipher.html)

Using PyCharm Python Packages tab to install, I still had to run the script before the red squiggles went away, but your import statement did not throw any errors.